# Why does Spark DF.write() operation cause deadlock with a jdbc connection on a table containing PKs?

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, databricks, primary-key, deadlock

I am trying to ingest data into an MS SQL Server Database. I am using `df.write()` operation on Databricks.

Writing the data to the said table succeeds if I remove the Primary Key(s) from the table but causes a deadlock if I try to run the write operation on the table with Primary Key(s) in it.

Here's the code, run on Databricks, that I am using to insert data into the MS SQL Database table:

```
    df = df.distinct()
        try:
          df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode(
              "append"
          ).option(
            "isolationLevel", "SERIALIZABLE"
          ).option(
              "url",
              f"jdbc:sqlserver://{self.server_name};databaseName={db_name};",
          ).option(
              "dbtable", f"{schema}.{table_name}"
          ).option(
              "inferSchema", "false"
          ).option(
              "user", self.username
          ).option(
              "password", self.password
          ).save()
        except Exception as e:
          self.logger.error(str(e))
```

I have put `distinct` there to avoid duplicates. Also, I have tried using the `isolationLevel` set to `serializable`. But the deadlock is still occurring.

Comment: try df.coalesce(10)